# C# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int MIN_AGE = 5;
            const int MAX_AGE = 7;
            const bool OVERRIDE_REQUEST = true;
            int age = 6;

            !OVERRIDE_REQUEST || age >= MIN_AGE && age <= MAX_AGE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried everything but it still gives an error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to find out if the statement is true

Comment: Maybe try a Console.WriteLine(!OVERRIDE_REQUEST || age >= MIN_AGE && age <= MAX_AGE) ?

Comment: +gawicks that worked

Comment: @Abdulhamid going forward please try not to put the question in the title! And have the full question and relevant information in the body of the question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since

```
!OVERRIDE_REQUEST || age >= MIN_AGE && age <= MAX_AGE;
```

expression returns a [boolean expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691320%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you need to assign it to something. Like;,

```
bool result = !OVERRIDE_REQUEST || age >= MIN_AGE && age <= MAX_AGE;
```

But since `OVERRIDE_REQUEST` is `true` as `const`, you can simplify your expression as;

```
bool result = age >= MIN_AGE && age <= MAX_AGE; // true
```

Then you can check it with [if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664746%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you want to.

```
if(result)
{
   // true
}
else
{ 
  // false
}
```