# Compilation error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

I have previously read:

[C# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249248/c-sharp-only-assignment-call-increment-decrement-and-new-object-expressions)

[Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement and ; Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592009/only-assignment-call-increment-decrement-and-new-object-expressions-can-be-u)

And I am writting the following:

```
namespace Converter {
      public class Converter
      {
        public string dnaToRna(string dna)
        {
          string rna = "";
          foreach(char letter in dna){
            letter=='T' ? rna+='U' : rna+=letter;
            rna+=letter;
          }
          return rna;
        }
      }
    }
```

When I call the code with the tests:

```
    namespace Converter {
  using NUnit.Framework;
  using System;

  [TestFixture]
  public class Test
  {
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
      Converter converter = new Converter();
      Assert.AreEqual("UUUU", converter.dnaToRna("TTTT"));
    }
  }
}
```

It says:

```
src/Solution.cs(9,9): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

However if I replace it as:

```
namespace Converter {
  public class Converter
  {
    public string dnaToRna(string dna)
    {
      string rna = "";
      foreach(char letter in dna){
        if(letter=='T'){
          rna+='U';
        }else{
          rna+=letter;
        }
      }
      return rna;
    }
  }
}
```

It works, why?

Thanks for your help .

Comment: The conditional operator is an *expression*. It's meant to return a *value*. Not contain *arbitrary* other statements.

Comment: This is about the time you need to read the documentation [?: Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) Fun level 100

Answer (score 5):

Incorrect:

```
letter=='T' ? rna+='U' : rna+=letter;
```

Correct:

```
rna+= letter=='T' ? 'U' : letter;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) is supposed to return a value. It is not meant as a substitution for an if statement to execute code. Doing anything else would be a [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), that is change things outside of what it is meant to do.
Instead of altering things during what is supposed to be one of two possible return values, you should determine what kind of return you want and use that.

```
rna += (letter=='T') ? 'U' : letter;
```

Comment: This is not correct. Of course you can execute code in a ternary statement. The point is that the result has to be assigned to something. This statement is perfectly valid and would give the result the OP intended: `rna = letter=='T' ? rna+='U' : rna+=letter;`

Comment: @iakobski still bad practice. and I never said it was impossible. Your bit of code makes no sense. Using the return value from an asignment is horrible style.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't perform assignment inside the ternary conditional itself; you should use this instead.

```
rna += letter=='T' ? 'U' : letter;
```

Syntax:

```
Boolean Expression ? First Statement : Second Statement
```

Note:

Ternary operator returns a value or expression included in the second or third part of it. It does not execute the statements.

Comment: How is your first example going to help, parentheses or not, its just not going to work

Comment: `It does not execute the statements.` it does, otherwise it couldn't return their values. That's not a valid syntax for the ternary operator either, that's the syntax that *caused* the OP's compilation error